# Is it safe to echo data on a page?

Tags: php, security

I have a form where users enter in a web template and they can preview it in their browser.

This page is only viewable by them:

```
<?php
echo "<title>".htmlspecialchars($_POST['title'], ENT_QUOTES)."</title><br/>";
echo nl2br($_POST['body']);
?>
```

I realized when testing this that it can access my local css files/js files.  This made me wonder if this can possibly lead to a security attack?

The sites cookies have the domain flag and httponly flag. If the client tried to XSS they would only be exploiting themselves right?

Is it safe for my web server to echo $_POST?

Comment: AFAIK you are right, they'd only be exploiting themselves.  As long as you don't allow them to enter PHP code that you eval(), I don't see any security issues that could be used against you.

Comment: Thanks drew. I will remember not to use eval() publicly! No telling what query someone might try.

Comment: Yep with eval they could try to `echo file_get_contents('/some/sensitive/file/with_passwords.php')` and they'd be able to see it.  A lot of sites allow users to create their own profiles with HTML and have no problems. But depending on what you are doing, there may be a lot of XSS tricks you will need to filter out if lots of people will be visiting their URL within the context of your site where they could steal `document.cookie`

Answer (score 1):

You still want to protect against XSS even with the httponly flag for reasons presented here:
http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/postxss/. The attacker can steal other valuable information presented on the page, other than the cookies.